# how to make array result the value of a link in php

Tags: php, sql

I have an internal website I'm working on, the first part of it returns a query from a database, and provides stops on a delivery route. The next step needs to turn those results into a link, so now each stop on the route is a link. I want each route to have a value that will equal its name. So if row 1 returns the result "Hospital" then when I click on that link, it will take the value of "Hospital" to the next page.

Here's what I have so far, I have tried several different methods, such as adding an echo in the value of the link to display the variable, but nothing has worked.

```
<?php

$route_name=$_GET['route_name'];
$day=$_GET['day'];
$database=$_GET['database'];
$inches=$_GET['inches'];
$data="snow_removal" . $database;

/*use this line for localhost*/ $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","DB"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$query = "  SELECT customer
            FROM $data
            WHERE route_name=$route_name
            AND inches<=$inches
            AND $day
            ;";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Customers</th>
                                </tr>";

while($row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td> <a href='snow.php'> " . $row['customer'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Any ideas of pushes in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You mean like using a get request, where the next page will receive the get parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you have an issue with this part of the HTML:

```
<a href='snow.php'> " . $row['customer'] . "</a>
```

**Use a GET request as HREF: `snow.php?customer=x`**

You can pass the value (here maybe the customer name) via a GET request.

The passed data will show up in your `$_GET` superglobal.

(First parameter is appened to the URL with `?param=value`.
Following parameters are appened to that with `&param2=value`.
That enables you to multiple pairs: `page.php?param=value&param2=value`.)

---

I'd suggest changing this line

```
echo "<td> <a href='snow.php'>".$row['customer']."</a></td>";
```

into this:

```
echo "<td> <a href='snow.php?customer=".$row['customer']."'>".$row['customer']."</a></td>";
```

And... because that looks crappy, let's extract the URL construction.

So, we end up with the following two lines:

```
$url = 'snow.php?customer=' . $row['customer'];

echo "<td> <a href='".$url."'>".$row['customer']."</a></td>";
```

You can also call this URL manually: `snow.php?customer=hospital` (or any other customer, if you know the name).

Then on the `snow.php` page, handle the incomming `$_GET['customer']`